# How is possible to combine InfiniteLoader with WindowScroller?

Tags: react-virtualized

How can I create an infinite scroll list but in a window scroller? (the same as Facebook timeline - [Mock up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYGKB.png))?

Below is the code that I have tried, but it does not work as expected. It only displays the first items and after that it does not display anything more.

```
<div className={styles.WindowScrollerWrapper}>
    <InfiniteLoader
      isRowLoaded={this._isRowLoaded}
      loadMoreRows={this._loadMoreRows}
      rowCount={list.size}
      threshold={10}>
      {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
        <WindowScroller>
          {({ height, isScrolling, scrollTop }) => (
            <AutoSizer disableHeight>
              {({ width }) => (

                <List
                  ref={registerChild}
                  className={styles.List}
                  autoHeight
                  height={height}
                  width={width}
                  onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                  rowCount={list.size}
                  rowHeight={30}
                  rowRenderer={this._rowRenderer}
                  scrollToIndex={randomScrollToIndex}
                  />
              )}
            </AutoSizer>
          )}
        </WindowScroller>
      )}
    </InfiniteLoader>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance.

**Update**

Here is the URL to demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/akyEpZ0cXhfs2jtZgQmN

Comment: A Pnlkr demonstrating what's happening would be useful.

Comment: @brianvaughn   I have managed to put an example on plunker. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on [your Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/akyEpZ0cXhfs2jtZgQmN), here's a [corrected Plnkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/C7UYFmBhYqRbAxC5?preview) that shows how it should work. (You were forgetting to pass the `scrollTop` param from `WindowScroller` to the child `List`.)

Here you go:

```
    <InfiniteLoader
      isRowLoaded={this._isRowLoaded}
      loadMoreRows={this._loadMoreRows}
      rowCount={list.size}
      threshold={10}>
      {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
        <WindowScroller>
          {({ height, isScrolling, scrollTop }) => (
            <AutoSizer disableHeight>
              {({ width }) => (
                <List
                  ref={registerChild}
                  className="List"
                  autoHeight
                  height={height}
                  width={width}
                  onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                  rowCount={list.size}
                  rowHeight={30}
                  rowRenderer={this._rowRenderer}
                  scrollTop={scrollTop} />
              )}
            </AutoSizer>
          )}
        </WindowScroller>
      )}
    </InfiniteLoader>
```

Comment: What if the height is not known beforehand — just like FB newsfeed?

Comment: Use `CellMeasurer` (https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md). It's mentioned pretty prominently in the docs. Check 'em out.